# Running Amazon product api based application via proxy to avoid throttle

Tags: amazon-mws

I am making an application based on Amazon Product API (or could be MWS), I will need to fetch data huge information again and again. So, in order to avoid Throttling limits, i would like to use Proxy ips.

Is this a valid thing to do.
1. Is the throttling limit apply per MWS account or per IP address
2. There are several proxy hosts avaialble for free/commerical. Is it ok to use them.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Valid? not really.

Amazon has some sharp people working there. I'm pretty sure this scheme wouldn't last very long. Your api access would be revoked pretty quickly.

Comment: If not using MWS or product advertising API, how about web screen scrapping using Proxy hosts. Is that a good idea? Just wondering how this guy achieved "http://zonasinhunter.com/" such fast scrapping results.